# Induced group action on cohomology of vector bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry, group-actions, vector-bundles, sheaf-cohomology

Let $p:E\to X$ be a vector bundle on a smooth projective curve $X$. Let $\Gamma$ be a finite subgroup of $Aut(X)$ which has a lifted action on $E$.

> How do we get an induced action of $\Gamma$ on $H^i(X,E)$?

I can see how the action could be defined for $i=0$ as these are just sections. What can we do for $i>0?$

Comment: As your $X$ is a curve, there is only one case $i = 1$, right? In this case you can use Serre duality $$H^1(X,E) \cong H^0(X,E^\vee(K_X))^\vee,$$ which is compatible with the group actions.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the action is on $H^0(E^* \otimes K)$?

Comment: You should specify what kind of cohomology this is. One setting is to have a flat connection on the vector bundle and take cohomology with coefficients in the locally constant sheaf.

Comment: Expanding on Sasha's comment. An automorphism of the variety preserves the tangent bundle, and so acts on the canonical bundle. So in particular it acts on sections of the canonical bundle. Also using the action on E you get an action on sections of the dual bundle. Putting this together is what I believe that Sasha was alluding to,,

Comment: @Angry_Math_Person: as Nick L explained, the action is induced by the action on $E^\vee$ and the canonical action on $K_X$.

Comment: This seems circular; you’re saying the action on the other $H^0$ is compatible under Serre duality with the action on $H^1$. But that doesn’t answer the OP’s question of what the action on $H^1$ *is*.

Comment: @JakeLevinson: The OP mentioned that he understands the action on $H^0$, and I explain that the action on $H^1$ reduces to an action on $H^0$. Doesn't it answer the question?

Comment: @Sasha well, no: the question would just become "why does the duality isomorphism $H^1(X, E) \cong H^0(X, E^\vee(K_X))^\vee$ preserve the $G$-action"? There's no direct definition of how $G$ acts on $H^1(X, E)$ there.

Comment: I thought the question was on how to compute the G action. If so, reducing to an $H^0$ case and using the previous method of computation would answer it. If it was just about abstractly defining how G acts on the $H^i$, then would need an independent definition.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a description using Čech cohomology. An element $\alpha \in H^i(X, E)$ is represented by a choice of open cover $\{U_i\}$, together with a tuple of local sections of $E$ over each of the $(i+1)$-st order intersections of the $U_i$'s, of the form $U = U_{k_0} \cap \cdots \cap U_{k_i}$. These sections have to satisfy the cocycle conditions, and are considered up to coboundaries and up to refinement of open covers.

Now $g \in G$ acts on $\alpha$ by replacing the open cover by $\{gU_i\}$ and acting on the tuple of sections. It replaces each local section $s : U \to E|_U$ by the local section $gU \to E|_{gU}$ defined by $x \mapsto gs(g^{-1}x)$. Notice that this definition relies on the fact that $g : E \to E$ commutes with the projection $E \to X$ and $g : X \to X$. This data is the new element $g\alpha \in H^i(X, E)$.

A more abstract approach would be to say that this is ultimately about functoriality of cohomology, ignoring the details of how you wish to define it. The isomorphism $g : X \to X$ induces $H^i(X, E) \xrightarrow{\sim} H^i(X, g^*E)$. The additional data of the lift of the action to $E$ amounts to a bundle isomorphism $g^*E \xrightarrow{\sim} E$ for each $g$ (respecting multiplication), which induces $H^i(X, g^*E) \xrightarrow{\sim} H^i(X, E)$. Composing these gives $H^i(X, E) \xrightarrow{\sim} H^i(X, E)$. Unwinding these two steps gives the $x \mapsto gs(g^{-1}x)$ formula above.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this for further reading?